# Dialogflow: Satisfaction rating after every chatbot response

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'd like to add a satisfaction rating, which would be initiated by the chatbot (not the user) after each intent / response provided. I tried doing this as a follow up intent, but that results in having the user to type something before they get the prompt for satisfaction rating.
What is a convenient way to have this rating be triggered by the chatbot after each provided response?
The satisfaction rating can be something as simple as "Are you satisfied with this answer Y/N".

Comment: What will you do with the Y and N answer? Will you be storing the customer response Y/N after  each satisfaction rating? And have a counter for each Y and N answer?

Comment: I figured I'd send those to an endpoint and do analytics on how many questions got a positive / negative rating.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you already have a 3rd party tool to do the analytics of positive and negative response, you can just use multiple responses instead of using follow up intent so that the user won't have to type anything before they got to the satisfaction rating. You can just put your satisfaction rating: "Are you satisfied with this answer Y/N" as your second response to capture Yes/No or Y/N response from the user. Just click `ADD RESPONSES` under Responses Section

[image]

[image]

For further details about built-in responses you may refer to this GCP documentation: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-responses#platforms.

In creating response on platform-specific you may also check this GCP documentation for rich response messages: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-rich-messages#add